# Sylow theorem Cyclic sylow p subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

$p$ is the smallest prime dividing order of $G$. $P$ is a sylow p subgroup which is cyclic. Prove that $N_G(P) = C_G(P)$

This is my approach :
Since $P$ is sylow p subgroup so its order is some power of $p$. Now $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(P)$ which has order $p^{(a-1)}(p-1)$. Now If $p$ doesn't divide index of $C(P)$ in $N(P)$ I'm through, but I'm not being able to proof why $p$ will not divide $[N(P):C(P)]$

Comment: Hint: $P\subseteq C(P)$.

Comment: @user115654 No, that is not true. Take for example the cyclic subgroup of index $2$ in $Q_8$. This is normal but not central.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You're right. What I meant to say was: if $P$ is a cyclic subgroup, *contained in the center of a Sylow $p$-subgroup*, then $N(P) = C(P)$ (for $p$ the smallest prime dividing $|G|$).

Comment: @user115654 Indeed (still assuming $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group). In fact, in that case, the group has a normal subgroup of order coprime to $p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Your last statement cannot be true (except in a trivial case). Sylow subgroups for the smallest prime always exist, and their centers always contain nontrivial cyclic subgroups, but the whole group need not have a normal subgroup of order coprime to $p$ besides $\{e\}$ (e.g. if $G$ is simple)

Comment: @user115654 Yes, sorry, I mixed up a few things there. If the Sylow subgroup is central in its normalizer, then we get the conclusion, and if the Sylow is cyclic and the prime is the smallest, then the Sylow is central in its normalizer (as this question asks about).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I agree

Answer (score 1):

***First consider the case when $C_G(P)$ is a $p$-subggroup of $G$.***

Now since $C_G(P)\subseteq N_G(P)$, we have $C_G(P)\subseteq P$. (we have used the fact that $C_G(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup here.)

But since $P$ is cyclic we also have $P\subseteq C_G(P)$.

Thus $C_G(P)=P$.

Now by the $N/C$ theorem, we have $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$ divides $|\text{Aut}(P)|=p^{n-1}(p-1)$.

Using $C_G(P)=P$, we have $|N_G(P)|$ divides $p^{2n-1}(p-1)$.

Here use the fact that $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ to deduce that $|N_G(P)|$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Since $P\subseteq N_G(P)$, we must have $|N_G(P)|=p^n$, and therefore $N_G(P)=P$.

This gives $N_G(P)=C_G(P)$.

***Now suppose that $C_G(p)$ is not a $p$-subgroup of $G$.***

Then, since $P$ is cyclic, $P\subsetneq C_G(P)$.

Using the $N/C$ theorem we have $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$ divides $p^{n-1}(p-1)$.

But note that $p$ does not divide $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$.

Say $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|=k$.

Then $k|[p^{n-1}(p-1)]$.

Suppose $k>1$.

Since any prime factor of $k$ is greater than $p$, we have $\gcd(k,p)=1$.

Therefore $k|(p-1)$ but this is not possible since any prime factor if $k$ is greater than $p$.

Therefore $k=1$ and we are done.

Comment: I'm having a tough time with this step "Here use the fact that p is the smallest prime dividing |G| to deduce that |NG(P)| is a p-subgroup of G.

Since P⊆NG(P), we must have |NG(P)|=pn, and therefore NG(P)=P." Could you elaborate how exactly we know NG(P) is a p-subgroup?

Comment: As shown in the previous line, we have that $|N_G(P)|$ divides $p^{2n-1}(p-1)$. If $N_G(P)$ were not a $p$-group then there would be a prime $q\neq p$ such that $q|N_G(P)$. But since $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, we have that $q>p$. But then $q$ divides $p^{2n-1}(p-1)$, giving that $q|(p-1)$. But then $q<p$ and we have a contradiction.